# Question on a torsion-free module, not finitely generated, not free over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

A classic example is $\mathbb{Q}$ as an abelian group. In order to be free, it would require a proper subgroup to be the basis. It's clear to me, on an intuitive level, that no such subgroup exists. But I'm having trouble making this intuition  rigorous. My hunch is that such a subgroup would have to be of finite index, and there can be none such subgroup.

But why exactly can there be none in this case? Also, why in general must a basis be of finite index when considered as a subgroup? I'm looking for a formal way to express these properties.

Comment: Any two nonzero rationals are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$, so if $\mathbb{Q}$ were a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it would have rank $1$, i.e., would be cyclic, which is not true. I don't understand what you mean by a basis being a proper subgroup, any nontrivial subgroup is not going to be linearly independent, since an element and its inverse (when distinct) give nontrivial linear relations. And the trivial subgroup certainly can't be a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Theorem.** *Let $R$ be an integral domain. Then $Q$, the field of fractions of $R$, is a free $R$-module if and only if $R$ is a field.*

One direction is obvious.

Suppose $Q$ is free and that $x,y\in Q$ are nonzero. We can write $x=a/c$, $y=b/c$, so
$$
b\frac{a}{c}+(-a)\frac{b}{c}=0
$$
Therefore $x$ and $y$ are not linearly independent over $R$. Hence $Q$ must have rank $1$